# Excel 2007 VBA Assigning part of a named range to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, named

I have a table of monthly sales figures - FreqData1.  Each column represents a month and is numbered 1 to 12. The user chooses one of these numbers from a dropdown list.

I have the code to find the column number and I have tried to assign the data in that column to an array so I can use it copy it to a different spreadsheet but with my basic VBA knowledge and despite lots of searching  I have been unable to find the code as to how to do this or a different method to carry this out.

Can anyone help please

```
Sub AnnualFreqMacro()

   Dim TPNoInt As Long, BranchNoInt As Long, ColNo As Long
   Dim FreqArray()

   Worksheets("Freq data").Activate
   TPNoInt = Range("B42").Value
   BranchNoInt = Range("B41").Value

   ColNo = Application.Match(TPNoInt, Range("TPBr1"), 0)

   CharaArray = Range("FreqData1").Cells (1, ColNo), Cells(16, ColNo))

   End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I *think* this may work: Delete your `CharArray = ...` line and replace with: `With Range("FreqData1") //
   CharaArray = .Range(.Cells(1, ColNo), .Cells(16, ColNo)) // 
End With` (note the `//` is just to show where a line break is, don't actually include those).  The issue is how you're setting the range, `Range().Cells(), Cells()` isn't the context, you'd want something more like `Range(Cells(),Cells())`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is your answer: It's how you're using the range.

Delete your `CharArray = ...` line and replace with:

```
With Range("FreqData1")
   CharaArray = .Range(.Cells(1, ColNo), .Cells(16, ColNo)) 
End With
```

The issue is how you're setting the range, `Range().Cells(), Cells()` isn't the context, you'd want something more like `Range(Cells(),Cells())`.

Let's say "FreqData1" is the range `A10:A20`.  If you use

```
With Range("FreqData1")
    .Cells(1,1).Select 
End With
```

this will select the top left most cell (row 1, column 1) in the range "FreqData", so cell `A10` would be selected.

A final misc. point: [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  You can activate a sheet of course so you can follow your macro, but when setting variables to ranges/cell values, etc. it's best to qualify which sheet you are referring to.

```
Sub AnnualFreqMacro()
Dim TPNoInt As Long, BranchNoInt As Long, ColNo As Long
Dim FreqArray()
Dim freqWS  As Worksheet
Set freqWS = Worksheets("Freq data")
' Worksheets("Freq data").Activate ' removed this, since we have a variable for it now.

TPNoInt = freqWS.Range("B42").Value    ' see how I added the worksheet that we want to get B42's value from?
BranchNoInt = freqWS.Range("B41").Value
ColNo = Application.Match(TPNoInt, Range("TPBr1"), 0)
With freqWS.Range("FreqData1")    ' I'm assuming "FreqData1" is on this worksheet
    CharaArray = .Range(.Cells(1, ColNo), .Cells(16, ColNo))
End With
End Sub
```

I'm not positive if you *have* to qualify a named range's sheet, since it's a named range, but I added that just to be safe.

Edit2: Hm, oddly enough, if your named range "myRange" is `A1:A10`, you can still do `myRange.Range(myRange.cells(1,1),myRange.cells(1,2))`, even though there's no second column in the range, it just expands it. I thought it'd throw an error, but nope. Just to note.